# error TS2345: Argument of type 'SpyObj<Router>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Router'

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

After updating my node packages, I am getting errors on unit tests.

Relevant code:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

describe('Effects', () => {
  let router: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;

  beforeEach(() => {
      router = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigateByUrl']);
  });

...

})

"@angular/router": "^7.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.14"
```

And I am getting this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'SpyObj' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Router'.

Comment: `@types/jasmine` version `3.3.4`?

Comment: @penleychan 2.8.14